# Chef : does it revert changes done in subfolder

Tags: chef-infra

I am deploying an application using chef. It deploys a build with following structure ( toplevel folder >> subfolder >> propertyfile)-
MyAPP >> SubApp >> propertyfile.

If I change my "propertyfile" manually, will the next chef-client run revert it back to original?

Comment: Depends on how your recipe code looks like. Show it, please.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on it? what specifically you want to check in recipe?

Comment: Nope, you elaborate first^^. It totally depends on how your recipe is implemented. Either way is possible, it could be that your recipe keeps the file as it is or it replaces it with the one specified in the cookbook or the repository that you deploy (if you deploy from a repo - but we don't know).

Answer (score 0):

If the file is being controlled by a `file` or `template` resource, yes Chef will test and repair the content every time. If the file did not come from one of those resources, then probably not.